# Lambda expression to search char matrix for consecutive matching of chars

Tags: c#, lambda

I have been doing c# development for a couple of months now but is still quite new.

I was trying to figure out a solution to see if you can form a certain word through a matrix of chars by only using chars that can be reached diagonally, vertically or horizontally, where each char can only be used once.

So for example:

["A","L","A","T"]

["L","R","L","Y"]

["T","B","E","D"]

["P","S","G","R"]

ALL in this case can be created, but BET cannot.

I found an interesting solution to this problem, but is not able to figure out how it solves the problem..

Note that 'board' is the matrix of chars and the 'string' is the word that it should examine wether it can be found in the matrix or not and then return true or false.

Solution:

```
using System.Linq;
public class Boggle
{
  private string w;
  private char[][] b;

  public Boggle(char[][] board, string word)
  {  
    w = word;
    b = board;
   }

  public bool Check() => b.Where((a,r) => a.Where((ch, c) => TryCell(r, c, 0)).Any()).Any();

  private bool TryCell(int r, int c, int n)
  {
    if (r < 0 || r >= b.Length || c < 0 || c >= b.Length || b[r][c] != w[n]) return false;   
    if (++n == w.Length) return true;
    b[r][c] = '_';  
    var anyDirValid = ( TryCell(r-1, c-1, n) || TryCell(r-1, c, n) || TryCell(r-1, c+1, n)    ||    
                    TryCell(r,   c-1, n)                       || TryCell(r,   c+1, n) ||
                    TryCell(r+1, c-1, n) || TryCell(r+1, c, n) || TryCell(r+1, c+1, n) );
    b[r][c] = w[n-1];
    return anyDirValid;
  }

}
```

What confuses me is this lambda expression:
public bool Check() => b.Where((a,r) => a.Where((ch, c) => TryCell(r, c, 0)).Any()).Any();

What is the logic behind that makes this work? In this case it is the double use of Where statements combined with the double use of Any I cannot get my head around.

I have been coding some lambda expression before, but this I cannot simply understand..

Can someone please explain this to me?